# Add all files recursively from root with Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following recursive method that simply adds all the child items in a given folder to a list:

```
private List<TemplateFile> readTemplateFiles(String nextTemplateDir, String rootTemplateDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<TemplateFile> templateFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File file : new File(nextTemplateDir).listFiles()) {
        if (!file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().startsWith(".")) {
            templateFiles.add(TemplateFile.create(file, rootTemplateDir));
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            templateFiles.addAll(readTemplateFiles(file.getAbsolutePath(), rootTemplateDir));
        }
    }

    return templateFiles;
}
```

How could I refactor this method using the new Java 8 Stream API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Files.walk(start, options...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) to walk through a file tree recursively. This method returns a `Stream<Path>` consisting of all the `Path` starting from the given root.

> Return a `Stream` that is lazily populated with `Path` by walking the file tree rooted at a given starting file. The file tree is traversed *depth-first*, the elements in the stream are `Path` objects that are obtained as if by resolving the relative path against `start`.

```
private List<TemplateFile> readTemplateFiles(String nextTemplateDir, String rootTemplateDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return Files.walk(Paths.get(nextTemplateDir))
                .filter(path -> !path.getFileName().startsWith("."))
                .map(path -> TemplateFile.create(path.toFile(), rootTemplateDir))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Among the [options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html), there is [`FOLLOW_LINKS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html#FOLLOW_LINKS) that will follow symbolic links.